# How do I generate ASCII codes 2 and 3 in a Bash command line?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ascii

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> that ought to give me ASCII code 2, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is going to be interpreted as a Break.

So I figure I've got to redirect a file in.  How do I get these characters into a file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> escapes the next keystoke.  That's how you can get a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> out: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

```
echo $'\002\003' > ./myfile
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -e 'print "\xFF"'
```

where `FF` is the hex code of the ACSII code you want to print. So for ACSII code 2, it would be \x02.